# ENOENT: no such file or directory \node_modules\install-cmake\bin\cmake'

Tags: node.js, cmake, npm-install, windows-build-tools

I'm trying to run `npm install` but it shows the next message:

[image]

It is weird, because I have installed `cmake`:

[image]

All node_modules specify on my `packages.json` are downloaded except for `install-cmake`.
All this issues started try to install `npm i windows-build-tools` and after some time dealing with issues I could install `npm i --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0` and the output was the next:

[image]

I'm using node v12.18.1 and npm 6.0.1

Comment: SInce you are getting a warning that you version of npm does not support Node.js v12.18.1 it's maybe time to update it to a supported version.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the question post as **text**, not linked as *image*. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] the question post accordingly.